# How to upload image on Twitter

Tags: iphone

I want to upload image on Twitter.

please any one help me how we upload image on Twitter.
Please explain or provide code.

Answer (score 2):

The following is to utilize Twitpic.

As said by others you have to start by looking at the [API](http://www.twitpic.com/api.do) to understand the requests.

You can use [Oliver Drobnik](http://www.drobnik.com)'s Tutorial : [Uploading UIImages to TwitPic](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/02/uploading-uiimages-to-twitpic/) which does it from scratch using `NSMutableURLRequest`

or you can use the [asi-http-request](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) which is a CFNetwork wrapper for HTTP requests

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToPost);
NSURL *twitpicURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitpic.com/api/uploadAndPost"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:twitpicURL] autorelease];

[request setData:imageData forKey:@"media"];
[request setPostValue:@"myUsername" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"myPassword" forKey:@"password"];
[request setPostValue:@"myMessage" forKey:@"message"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];

[request start];
```

You should look at the first.. **first** that way you understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a "twitter-picture-provider" like [TwitPic](http://twitpic.com/) or [TweetPhoto](http://tweetphoto.com/). They usually provide their own APIs as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks can you please explain how to upload image using TwitPic.

Or send me code for using it.

Comment: Not much better than the documentation (http://dev.twitpic.com/) itself. If you've got no experience in using such APIs, you should google it a bit. I have never developed for the iPhone (or the TwitPic API for that matter), so I cannot give any concrete code. Some googling, the documentation and some work is pretty much what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not host image uploads at the moment.  You have to use a third-party service.  [Yfrog](http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/) and [Twitpic](http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/) are the two most popular on Twitter.

Comment: Can you explain how we used ASIFormDataRequest class.
How we get code of ASIFormDataRequest  class.

Answer (score 0):

first import twitter frame work after that u write this code

```
    TWTweetComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler completionHandler =^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
    {
        switch (result) {
            case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"twitter result:cancelled");

                break;
                case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"twitter result:sent");
        } 
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tvc = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if(tvc)
    {
        [self addTweetContentContent:tvc];
       tvc.completionHandler = completionHandler;
        [self presentModalViewController:tvc animated:YES];  
    }
```

the local method is....

```
-(void)addTweetContentContent:(id)tvc

{

UIImage *image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
 UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

or

```
 UIImage  *picture=[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
 [tvc addImage:picture];
NSString *tweetText = @"write your comands";
[tvc setInitialText:tweetText];
```

}